# Mysql syntax - Concat and limit lenght of field

Tags: mysql, char, field, concatenation

Mysql syntax error. Using concat, I need to limit a third field to 100 characters. This code returns the entire field not limited to 100 characters.

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="',posts_network.guid,'">',posts_network.post_title,'</a>','<p>',posts_network.post_content,100,'</p>') AS network_title_with_link_to_post FROM am_posts AS posts_network WHERE 1=1  AND posts_network.post_type = 'network'
```

The post_content show the entire field, not limited to 100 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use subtsr

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="',posts_network.guid,'">'
             ,posts_network.post_title,'</a>'
             ,'<p>'
             ,substr(posts_network.post_content,1,100),
             '</p>') AS network_title_with_link_to_post 
FROM am_posts AS posts_network 
WHERE 1=1  
AND posts_network.post_type = 'network'
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks Edge.